# Change color of vertical menu's <li> by css

Tags: css, colors, background, html-lists, css-selectors

I would like to change the color of vertical menu which is created in `<ul>` and `<li>` to color by its order. I don't want to give each `<li>` a class to make the background colorful. But I need css to count it - nth: for example.

Saying I have 10 menu items in `<li>` :

```
<ul>
<li>menu 1</li>
<li>menu 2</li>
<li>menu 3</li>
<li>menu 4</li>
<li>menu 5</li>
<li>menu 6</li>
<li>menu 7</li>
<li>menu 8</li>
<li>menu 9</li>
<li>menu 10</li>
</ul>
```

Then I need to use css to change the background color and hover state of each element. So I applied the css:

```
ul li:nth-child(1) {  
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

And I stuck here. I don't have an idea how to make each `<li>` a specified background-color. Would you guys please suggest a brilliant solution.

Regards,

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Please give a concrete expected outcome based on your sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, 'color' refers to font color.  You want to use background-color.  So your CSS would look like

```
ul li:nth-child(1) {  
  background-color: #ccc;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: rgb(60,100,60);
}
etc....
```

If you want to stripe it with alternating colors you can do this

```
ul li:nth-child(odd) {  
  background-color: #ccc;
}
ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(60,100,60);
}
```

Comment: faludi, your solution is quite interesting. By your method, can I also make it a hover state by doing this: `li:nth-child(1):hover{background-color:red}` ???

Comment: faludi, your solution works! Thanks for the help. Case closed!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to set up classes for the colors, say

```
.green {
 background-color:green;
}

.red {
 background-color:red;
}
```

That way you can simple assign classes to each of your list elements

```
<li class="green"></li>
```

plus the added advantage is that you are not styling all ul elements on your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

As @faludi has mentioned, you can refer to each `li` starting with `1` - `nth-child(1)` and so on. Or you can just use `odd` and `even`.

For the hover color, you can do the following...

```
ul li:hover {
  background-color: #bbbfff;  
}
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/4ap8P/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li:nth-child(1) {  
  background-color: #ccc;
}
ul li:nth-child(1):hover {  
  background-color: #ddd;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: rgb(60,100,60);
}
ul li:nth-child(2):hover {
  background-color: rgb(60,100,100);
}
```

Solution from **faludi**, detecting li element of vertical menu and change background by its order.